# ENTITY RELATION USING SPACY LIBRARY WITH PYTHON

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

Question: 
Apple and Google are 400 billion and 500 billion dollars respectively

Answer:

Apple -> 400 billion

Google -> 500 billion

How to find entity relation using spacy library with python

My code below is good or i need to train(with Custom Named Entity Recognizer) ?
Im not getting accurate answer for various input

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp("Apple and Google are 400 billion and 500 billion dollars respectively")

for i in doc:
    if i.pos_ == "NOUN" and i.dep_ == "nsubj":
        for j in i.head.subtree:
            if j.dep_ == 'attr' or j.dep_ == 'prep' or j.dep_ == 'pobj':
                print(i)

for i in doc.ents:
    print(i)
```

Comment: You should add some sample input and the corresponding output to show both correct results and wrong results.

Comment: Part of the problem is that `Apple` and `Google` are of `pos_=PROPN`. Check out the `i.subtree` attribute